# What is the difference between Either<string, A> and Either<Error, A>

Tags: fp-ts

I'm new to `fp-ts`, I saw some people use `Either<string, A>` and others use `Either<Error, A>` in different articles. I want to know the difference between the two, and how should I choose which one to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Either` is a tool to help you return one of two possible values from a function. Traditionally it is used to message to the call site when a process can fail. Failures are returned in the `Left` variant, whereas successful values are returned in the `Right` variant.

So with `Either<string, A>` the function is promising to return the `Right<A>` value when it succeeds or a `Left<string>` value when it fails. In that case, the failure is most likely a string containing a message describing the failure. `Either<Error, A>` is similar, except that the author of that function is using the existing `Error` class to contain information about the failure.

It's up to the designer of the function's API to decide what value it makes sense to return on failure, but neither is necessarily wrong.

Incidentally, the `Left` value being failure and the `Right` value being success is only convention. It's perfectly valid to have a function that returns `Either<number, string>` and return `number` in some situations and `string` in others.